# Jquery animate fly out and back in

Tags: jquery, html

There are a bunch of questions about toggling animation, but I can't figure this out and those didn't help out too much.

What I'm trying to do is have a hero unit with 4 divs. On-click, I would like each one to fly out in a different direction, get new content, then fly back in. What I'm having a problem with is the first time you click, it flys out, gets an update, and flys back in. However the second time, it just flys out and never comes back.

Code:
**HTML**

```
<ul class="feature-nav">
    <li id="overview" class="text-center"><i class="icon-tasks icon-small"></i>
        <br />Overview</li>
</ul>
<div class="overview">
     <h1>Features</h1>

    <div class="feature-left pull-left">Content here</div>
    <div class="feature-right pull-right">right content</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="feature-bottom">bottom content</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.feature-nav li').on('click', function () {
            var item_clicked = $(this).attr('id');
            features();
            $('.overview').delay(1000).queue(function () {
                features_back(item_clicked);
            });
        });
    });

    function features() {
        $('.overview h1').animate({
            right: "1000px"
        }, 300);
        $('.overview .feature-left').animate({
            right: "1000px"
        }, 700);
        $('.overview .feature-right').animate({
            bottom: "300px",
            opacity: '0'
        }, 400);
        $('.overview .feature-bottom').animate({
            top: "100px",
            opacity: '0'
        }, 400);

    }

    function features_back(item_clicked) {
        $('.overview h1').html('New Header').animate({
            right: "0"
        }, 300);
        $('.overview .feature-left').html('New Left Content').animate({
            right: "0"
        }, 500);
        $('.overview .feature-right').html('New right Content').animate({
            bottom: "0",
            opacity: '1'
        }, 400);
        $('.overview .feature-bottom').html('New bottom Content').animate({
            top: "0",
            opacity: '1'
        }, 400);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out.

removed

```
$('.overview').delay(1000).queue(function () {
    features_back(item_clicked);
});
```

and replaced it with:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    features_back(item_clicked);
}, 1000);
```